# Could not connect to TCP port: Connection refused when trying to open Expo app on Android Emulator in WSL2

Tags: expo, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been following this guide https://medium.com/@pellea/using-adb-with-wsl2-7aebbb070a47 and so far have gotten to the point where WSL2 can see the emulator(s) running on Windows through Android Studios -> AVD manager. For example, on both Windows and WSL2, `adb devices` correctly shows:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

However, when I go to my expo app and try to launch the Android emulator, **I get the following error message**:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5554: Connection refused
```

This is after I've tried the following:

1. exporting `ADB_SERVER_SOCKET=tcp:<MY IP>:5037` in my WSL2 profile(s)
2. Unblocking WSL2 vEthernet connections from my Windows firewall via (from the above link)

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -DisabledInterfaceAliases "vEthernet (WSL)"
```

3. I've portforwarded 5554 from Windows to WSL2, as well as 5037 (from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1):

```
$WSL_CLIENT = bash.exe -c "ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet\s)\d+(\.\d+){3}'";
$WSL_CLIENT -match '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}';
$WSL_CLIENT = $matches[0];
iex "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5554 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=5554 connectaddress=$WSL_CLIENT"
```

The ports are as follows:

```
netsh interface portproxy show all

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
127.0.0.1       8081        172.25.38.171   8081
0.0.0.0         5037        127.0.0.1       5037
127.0.0.1       5554        172.29.149.0    5554
```

Comment: Was this ever solved @Richard? I did everything the same except port forwarding, was that the solution?

Comment: @PeterS I did not find a fix unfortunately. I've been either using Expo Go or custom development clients (with Expo EAS) on a real android device, or developing on my Mac if I want to use the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

Just had the same issue with Expo.

Here is what fixed it for me:

1. Check for a process that uses port 5555 (Terminal)

   ```
   netstat -ano | findstr 5555
   ```
2. Kill the process using its ID (PowerShell)

   ```
   Stop-Process -ID [PROCESS_ID] -Force
   ```

Then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, but with a different setup (using Expo with the Metro bundler on a Mac). I worked around it by trying different virtual device images. Maybe the same can help you.

The virtual device that works with me so far is the one selected in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFTJ0.png.  The other two in the screenshot have the same problem.  I don't really know the actual reason, must be something with port access with those other emulated devices.

Image details:
Name: 4 WVGA (Nexus S) API 29
API: 29
Target: Android 10.0 (Google APIs)
CPU/ABI (x86)

I'm sure other images work as well (or configuring the others somehow), i just haven't tried many more because it takes so long and they're so big.

Comment: No luck: I actually can telnet fine into the AVD prompt from WSL2 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830917/how-can-i-get-expo-to-connect-to-android-emulator-with-a-non-localhost-ip-addres) but Expo somehow can't pick up the emulator from my Windows IP.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to map port 5554 to Windows IP instead? (or localhost). The Android emulator is running on Windows, not WSL2, so the port proxy should be from WSL2 to Windows, not backwards.

Have you already solved it in another manner?

Comment: I just tried mapping the reverse (flipping the listen/connect addresses) and that did not seem to work. I have not yet solved this.

Comment: Another thing you can do is, if you want to use an emulator, just create a device with Google Play Store. Download on that emulated device the expo app and connect to the expo server by LAN. You can do so if you create a portproxy for 90000 and 90001 from windows to WSL2. Then just copy the `exp://<your-windows-ip>:90000` and the emulator will get it from the clipboard.

I tried it on my PC and its working. I can explain it better on an answer if you want to.

Comment: @AitorAlonso Can you explain further like Im a noob XD

Comment: Here you go @rickerp 

https://gist.github.com/tairosonloa/cd848c6f6befb6ba0a0af6924d66ea7e

I'm not working with Expo since November, but I hope the explanation to be accurate enough.