# How can I get expo to connect to Android emulator with a non-localhost ip address?

Tags: expo

I have an Android Emulator running on Windows on port 5554.

I am running expo inside WSL2. I have verified that I can access my Android Emulator on WIndows since if I type in:

```
# 172.22.80.1 is the IP to Windows from WSL2
telnet 127.22.80.1 5554
```

it shows me the same "Android Console: Authentication required" prompt as if I did it in my Windows PowerShell.

However, when I click on "Run on Android device/emulator" from the Metro Bundler web page, it throws me:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: could not connect to TCP port 5554: Connection refused
```

It seems like it's trying to access the emulator via `localhost:5554`, but I would like it to connect to `$SPECIFIED_IP:5554`.

Is there an env var where I can change this? FWIW I am using a Managed Expo project.

Comment: I'm actually going the other way (WSL2 --> Windows), and I've gotten that to work by doing the port forwarding + enabling inbound firewall rules. The issue I'm having is expo related where I'd like to change the IP address that expo connects to when launching an Android emulator.